# Legend Modification in Gnuplot 4.6

Tags: split, gnuplot, legend

Hello fellow stackoverflow users,

I have been sitting for several days on the following problem with which I need your help.
I would like to create a plot for my thesis, which should resemble the embedded plot.

[image: 1]

Line type, etc all pose no problem at all.
However, I would like to create a similar legend in my plot. I don't even know what keywords to search for. I have tried a few things from other stackoverflow posts i found, but nothing provides an adequate result.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add links for the "other posts", so that we can follow your search?

Comment: @Arthy how does your data look like? Is it one file with 8 columns of data or several files with a certain number of columns? Please clarify. Existing (not necessarily working) code and an example of typical data would always help.

Comment: @Arthy can you clarify what does legend modification mean? If I understood correctly, you want have a 3 column legend?

Answer (score 0):

Good question, and I don't know of a good way to produce the type of legend you ask for.
The lines and numbers (the "body" of the table, so to say) can be achieved rather easily with the `maxrows` option of `set key`.

But the real challenge are the column headers. In gnuplot, a key entry is always build from a sample of the plot style (line, point...) and a text string. I first tried to add the column headers via `keyentry`, however, this will not give any string at the place where the plot sample would be. I can only suggest a workaround: Build the table body as a key, and add the column headers with a manually placed `label`.

```
array numbers[4] = [0.60, 0.64, 0.68, 0.70]
set key t r maxrows 4 vertical width -5 at graph 0.95, 0.9
set label 1 '{/:Italic t}/ms Flamelet DNS  ' at graph 0.95,0.925 r
plot for [i=1:4] i*x w l lc i t sprintf('%.2f', numbers[i]), for [i=1:4] i w p lc i t ' '
```

Assuming that you use LaTeX for your thesis, you could of course replace the formatting in the label to LaTeX syntax: `set label 1 '$t$/ms ...`.
Most probably the amount of spaces will need several iterations of finetuning before you are happy with the result.

But maybe someone else has a nicer, less "hacky" solution?

PS: arrays require gnuplot >= 5.2, in 4.6 you might instead use a string of numbers and split it with `word()`, however, this has no effect on the approach. Anyway, you might consider updating, the current stable release is 5.4.

[image]

Comment: As you say, arrays have been implemented in gnuplot 5.2, but are not available in gnuplot 4.6 (see OP's question title). But in gnuplot versions <5.2, it could be done via `word()`.

Comment: @theozh Right, thanks, I added a remark about `word()`. Anyway, it doesn't make the initial problem better or worse :-)